# Split roundered corner using mdframed

Tags: mdframed

I would like to create splitted rounder corner with separate frametitle (attached below) using mdframed or mdframed with tikz. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{emacexmfont}{cmyk}{0.7,0.63,0.7,0}
\definecolor{examplebckcolor}{cmyk}{0,0.2,0.25,0}
\begin{document}
\mdfsetup{%
   middlelinecolor=examplebckcolor,
   middlelinewidth=2pt,
   backgroundcolor=examplebckcolor,
   roundcorner=20pt}
\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of table that asker is trying to achieve]

Comment: How about using `tcolorbox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: coloured boxes, not to my taste!]

A beginning which should give you the idea. See the manual for further options:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{emacexmfont}{cmyk}{0.7,0.63,0.7,0}
\definecolor{examplebckcolor}{cmyk}{0,0.2,0.25,0}
\tikzset{
  my example style/.style={font=\sffamily\bfseries, anchor=west, align=left, text=blue},
}
\newcounter{example}
\setcounter{example}{0}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{% based on example 6 in the manual
  \stepcounter{example}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node [my example style, text width=.2\linewidth] {\strut Example~\theexample};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node (some node) [my example style, text width=.2\linewidth] {\strut Example~\theexample:};
          \node [my example style, right=0pt of some node, text=blue!60!cyan, text width=.75\linewidth] {\strut #1};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \mdfsetup{%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=yellow,
    linecolor=white,%
    linewidth=0pt,
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlerulewidth=2.5pt,
  }\relax
  \begin{mdframed}%
}{%
  \end{mdframed}%
}
\begin{document}
  \mdfsetup{%
    backgroundcolor=examplebckcolor,
    roundcorner=20pt}
  \begin{example}
    \lipsum[3]
    \lipsum[4]
  \end{example}
  \begin{example}[An Example]
    \lipsum[3]
    \lipsum[4]
  \end{example}
\end{document}
```